# How to find y_test in original test set

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am new to machine learning and I'm currently working on linear regression models.

I am trying to find the prediction score of my linear regression model but I can't find a way of extracting the y_test from the test set.

Using a train-test split on other datasets, it is straight forward on how to get the y_test. My challenge is on how to get it from data sets that have already been split.

Comment: Hi Christopher, could you explain which dataset you are using and possibly post the code that you use to run your linear regression? This will help us know how to help you

Comment: One extremely tedious CPU-intensive way which would take *forever* on a big data set, is to brute force re-fit gazillions of combinations of the original data set until you have an exact matching prediction score to 15 decimal places.

Comment: Hi @colelemonz, the question states that performing a linear regression is no problem, so posting his working code does not help answer the question on recovery of previously split  y_test data.

Comment: Thank you. I have two datasets, train and test, from which I've been able to find the x_train, y_train and x_test. Where I'm stuck is on finding the the y_test in order to compute the regression score and RMSE.

Comment: If you have the entire original data set, you might in theory be able to search through it for a known value of x to find the corresponding value of y. Is it possible in this case to use the known x_test values to search for corresponding y values? Note the caveat that there may be duplicate x_test values in the dataset if you have not yet verified that the x_test values are all distinct in the original data.